# How can I cleanly link Enums to the static information within classes?

Tags: java, enums, static

For the sake of clarity, I will do my best to frame the question through the lens of an example, rather than a code dump.

**Before getting into my example, my question is as follows:** How can I write a method that takes an enum as a parameter, and returns the static-information stored in an object (which inherits from a communal parent, where the static information is defined).

**The example:**

I am creating a game which includes many player-skills. These skills are created via an object tree, with the following inheritance (SomeSkill represents any of a dozen or so skills):

*Skill > ActiveSkill > SomeSkill* **and** *Skill > PassiveSkill > SomeSkill*

**Psuedo-code for the class Skill:**

```
    Class Skill{
       static string name = "Default Skill"
       int level;
       Skill(int level){
          this.level = level;
       }
       static getName{
          return name;
       }
    }
```

Name is static, since the name of the skill shouldn't change, regardless of the intance. In my actual implementation, Skill also includes static information *description*, and *id*.

**Actual implementation of enum**:

```
   public enum SkillType
   {
     basic, speed_buff, leap, beat_down
   }
```

**The problem:**

What I am struggling to do is write a method that takes a SkillType enum as an argument, and returns a usable Skill object (NOT an instance of the Skill object)

**In Psuedo code:** As an example, if I wanted to loop through the Enum and print out the names of all skills...

```
    method getSkillClass(SkillType skillType){
       if(skillType == beat_down) return BeatDown
       if(skillType == leap) return Leap
       ...
    }

    for(e : SkillType.getKeys){
       print(getSkillClass(e).getName);
    }
```

My current "solution" would be to create a map that matches SkillType to a list of instanced out Skills, with all non-static skill information set to default values.

This seems like an abuse of the system though.

How can I cleanly link my enum-list to the static information (the non-static information can be ignored) in my various skill classes?

Comment: How is SkillType different from Skill? And why have both?

Comment: Also, when you say *"returns a usable Skill object (NOT an instance of the Skill object"* how is a Skill object not an instance of Skill object?

Comment: *"Name is static, since the name of the skill shouldn't change, regardless of the intance."* Many Java strings are interned, meaning this "optimization" probably isn't doing much for you and is only causing your design to be more complicated.

Comment: Based on the names in your enum: `speed_buff, leap, beat_down` it sounds to me like you should apply some polymorphic method in your base Skill class and not try to re-invent the typing system by declaring these types of skills separately from the skills themselves.

Comment: I think my big "failure" was not realizing the full power of Enums. I use the SkillType Enum as a simple way to pass around skills in a plaint-text format. For example if I run the in-game command `/giveSkill speed_buff`, I can create a variable s = SkillType.valueOf("speed_buff"). I can now pass s around my functions as I handle the command. I should definitely look into a more powerful application of Enum that does not require this odd if/if/else linkage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java enums allow a constructor that can be used to associate data to the enum:

```
class Skill {
    ...
}

public enum SkillType {
    Basic(new Skill(...)),
    SpeedBuff(new Skill(...)),
    Leap(new Skill(...)),
    ...

    private final Skill skill;

    public SkillType(Skill skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public Skill getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }
}
```

For further information, look at the 'Planet' example in the official [enum documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: Thank you! 
This has definitely given me some food-for-thought. As I mentioned above, my biggest failure was not realizing the full power of Enums. 
Time to start refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

As @Alex mentioned, you can use enum constructor, but instead of creating an instance for linking, you can link the `Class` type if you don't want to create instances:

```
public enum SkillType {
    Basic(Basic.class),
    SpeedBuff(SpeedBuff.class),
    Leap(Leap.class),
    ...

    private final Class skillClass;

    public skillClass(Class skillClass) {
        this.skillClass = skillClass;
    }

    public Class getSkillClass() {
        return skillClass;
    }
}
```

You can then use **reflection** techniques to get the static field information as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685345/getting-value-of-public-static-final-field-property-of-a-class-in-java-via-refle).